# Optional parameters on delegates doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, delegates, optional-parameters

Why this piece of code does not compile?

```
delegate int xxx(bool x = true);

xxx test = f;

int f()
{
   return 4;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Optional parameters are for use on the *calling* side - not on what is effectively like a single-method-interface *implementation*. So for example, this *should* compile:

```
delegate void SimpleDelegate(bool x = true);

static void Main()
{
    SimpleDelegate x = Foo;
    x(); // Will print "True"
}

static void Foo(bool y)
{
    Console.WriteLine(y);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What will happen `test(false)`? It will corrupt the stack, because signatures must match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
static int f(bool a)
{
  return 4;
}
```