# Using [CallerMemberName] Attribute with Func delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, callermembername

I have common class which is used by both GUI and CommandLine applications

This class is passed a ReportError function reference which acts differently on GUI and CommandLine.

in the GUI:

```
 public int GUIReportError(String ToLog)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ToLog);
        return 0;
    }
```

in the common Class members:

```
readonly Func<string, int> ReportError;
```

in the common Class Constructor:

```
public CommonClass(Func<string, int> ReportErrorFunc)
{
   ReportError=ReportErrorFunc;
}
```

Up to now, all is simple but I would integrate the [CallerMemberName] attribute to my log function

```
public int GUIReportError(String ToLog, [CallerMemberName] string CallingFunction="")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ToLog, CallingFunction);
            return 0;
        }
```

So I also updated the Func definition:

```
 readonly Func<string,  string?, int> ReportError;
```

**note udage of ? to tell it's optional parameter**

But When I call this ReportError function, I get a compiler error as follows:
**CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'arg2' of Func<string, string?,int>**

if anyone already experienced this kind of problem, I would really appreciate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optional arguments in a generic Func<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200009/optional-arguments-in-a-generic-func)

Comment: `string?` does not mean that the parameter is optional. `string?` is short for `Nullable<string>`

Comment: `string?` is the same a `string` because in C# `strings` can be `null`. Note this does not make the parameter optional.

Comment: @Sinatr, thanks for your quick support. Your second comment makes me think I have to split the problem in two: First I'll make an additional function in my common class which will gather the name of calling function through the [CallerMemberName] attribute and then pass it to the log funciton.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Solution is here.

The common Class declares a ReportError function which includes [CallerMemberName] as optional parameter.

This function then calls the delegate function passing 2 strings without having to deal with the optionnality.