# Delegate.DynamicInvoke can't use optional parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, delegates

look this code please :

```cs
// this method have a optional parameter
public static void Foo(int a = 3) { }

var del = new Action<int>(Foo);

// pass Type.Missing
del.DynamicInvoke(Type.Missing);

// or
del.DynamicInvoke(new object[] { Type.Missing });
```

it will get exception `System.ArgumentException`:

```
System.ArgumentException: Missing parameter does not have a default value.
Parameter name: parameters
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at xxx.btnSetting_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in xxx\FmMain.cs:line 106
```

please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using C# delegates with methods with optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729154/using-c-sharp-delegates-with-methods-with-optional-parameters)

Comment: @thehennyyHmmm, not really, that question is about match delegate and method, this question is about executing problem. please cancel duplicate flag, thank you.

Comment: The linked answers explaining the situation even if the question is not the same.

Comment: @thehennyyI don't think so, this problem is about `DynamicInvoke`, no answer talk it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that problem in using of `Action<int>`, seems like it doesn't support dynamic invocation of optional args. This sample is working fine

```
// this method have a optional parameter
public static void Foo(int a = 3) { }

delegate void SampleDelegate(int a = 3);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SampleDelegate del = Foo;
    // pass Type.Missing
    del.DynamicInvoke(Type.Missing);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it cause method's defaultValue is ignored, i think this is a bug about `DynamicInvoke`, so depressing.