# Assigning a method to a delegate where the delegate has more parameters than the method

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a delegate that takes quite a few parameters like so:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(float thereAre, int lotsOf, string parametersIn, int thisDelegate);
public MyDelegate theDelegateInstance;
```

This gets quite annoying because Visual Studio 2010 doesn't have any sort of auto complete to help a method match a delegate signature. I basically want to be able to write a method that takes only some of (or none of) the parameters of the delegate and just ignores the others because it doesn't use them anyway.

```
theDelegateInstance += delegate()
{
    Debug.Log("theDelegateInstance was called");
};
```

Or

```
theDelegateInstance += delegate(float thereAre, int lotsOf)
{
    if(thereAre > lotsOf) Debug.Log("thereAre is way too high");
};
```

I've found that I can make a method take a delegate return a MyDelegate that calls it like so:

```
public delegate void VoidMethod();

public static MyDelegate ConvertToMyDelegate(VoidMethod method)
{
    return delegate(float thereAre, int lotsOf, string parametersIn, int thisDelegate)
    {
        method();
    };
}
```

But that requires me to declare a static method for each different conversion.

I just found that I could do my first example without any parameters to achieve the desired result:

```
theDelegateInstance += delegate//Notice that there are no brackets here.
{
    Debug.Log("theDelegateInstance was called");
};
```

But that only works for inline methods that take no parameters. If I wanted to use even one of the parameters like the second example, I would need to have all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do it with lambdas.

You can do it in two ways - using your two example functions that you want to call:

First way - Create the method, and invoke it directly:

```
void FirstFunction(float thereAre, int lotsOf)
{
    if(thereAre > lotsOf) 
        Debug.Log("thereAre is way too high");
}
```

And invoke it this way:

```
theDelegateInstance += (t, l, p, td) => FirstFunction(t, l);
```

Second way - just do the call directly without creating the function:

```
theDelegateInstance += 
    (t, l, p, td) => Debug.Log("theDelegateInstance was called");
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be possible. All you need is to use an optional parameter in your delegate.

Look at Jon Skeet's [answer].

> Optional parameters are for use on the calling side - not on what is effectively like a single-method-interface implementation. So for example, this should compile:

```
delegate void SimpleDelegate(bool x = true);

static void Main()
{
    SimpleDelegate x = Foo;
    x(); // Will print "True"
 }

 static void Foo(bool y)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(y);
 }
```

([Optional parameters on delegates doesn't work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636218/optional-parameters-on-delegates-doesnt-work-properly)).

Comment: Please include an example in your answer (in addition to a link if you want) rather than having your answer rely on the link.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you're asking for is a method that returns a lambda like this:

```
public static MyDelegate ConvertToMyDelegate(VoidMethod method)
{
    return (thereAre, lotsOf, parametersIn, thisDelegate) => method();
}
```

Fortunately for you, .Net contains a way of creating lambdas programmatically. This means you can create just one generic `Convert` method, that will handle any number of parameters in both delegate types:

```
public static TTarget ConvertDelegate<TSource, TTarget>(TSource sourceDelegate)
{
    if (!typeof(Delegate).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TSource)))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("TSource must be a delegate.");
    if (!typeof(Delegate).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TTarget)))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("TTarget must be a delegate.");
    if (sourceDelegate == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("sourceDelegate");

    var parameterExpressions = typeof(TTarget)
        .GetMethod("Invoke")
        .GetParameters()
        .Select(p => Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType))
        .ToArray();

    var sourceParametersCount = typeof(TSource)
        .GetMethod("Invoke")
        .GetParameters()
        .Length;

    var expression = Expression.Lambda<TTarget>(
        Expression.Invoke(
            Expression.Constant(sourceDelegate),
            parameterExpressions.Take(sourceParametersCount)),
        parameterExpressions);

    return expression.Compile();
}
```